# How to obtain a list of all terms in a field for a given DocSet in a custom Solr SearchComponent?

Tags: solr, lucene, faceted-search, solr4

I'm trying to create a custom `SearchComponent` for Solr based on the `FacetComponent`. In a nutshell, I just need a list of the same terms that would appear in the facet but, instead of just having a count of the documents containing that term in that given query, I need a custom function of that count and the docFreq for that term.

I've been looking through the code of the `FacetComponent` and see that it somehow uses the `DocValuesFacets.getCount` method, but it is hundreds of lines long, check for each kind of facet result I could possibly want, and I couldn't find where exactly the list of terms and their counts to build the facet is retrieved.

The fields I want to do my thing on are always singleValued, so I really just need something very simple, like:

```
private NamedList<Double> myCustomFacet(DocSet docs, String fieldName) {
    NamedList<Double> results = new NamedList<Double>();
    List<Term> terms = functionThatGetTheListOfTerms(docs, fieldName); //how do I get this?
    for (term: Terms){
        Integer numDocs = searcher.numDocs(new TermQuery(term), docs);
        Integer docFreq = searcher.docFreq(luceneTerm);
        results.add(term, myCustomMetric(numDocs, docFreq);
    }
    return results;
}
```

so, given a DocSet and a field name, how do I retrieve the possible terms on that field for that DocSet?